# Reactjs Ajax returns first empty array while getting json object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, object, reactjs

I have a problem. I am learning React js and I have a template which i must edit. I need to add some ajax methods for getting and sending info. I manage to do some of those actions but now I have a problem.

I have php scripts which is getting me json_encode.

```
getCategories: function() {
$.ajax({
  url: '#########my_url#########',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    this.setState({datas: data});
  }.bind(this)
});
},
```

and I have this

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {datas: []};
},
```

The problem is I always get firstly the empty array and then the result. And when I try to work with it, it gets me error because it tries to map the empty array. This is the console.log before I try to play with the object.

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

[]

[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

How can I make it to work after the object is full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option: render your view on ajax call success

Second option: anticipate the case your state.datas is still empty

for example if you're working in your render function try:

```
   { this.state.datas ? <div> Loading </div> : <....
```

Above is JSX syntax

Hope it helps

**EDIT:**

```
if(this.state.datas.length == 0) {
    var mycomponent =<div> Loading ... </div>;
} else {
   var mycomponent = this.state.datas;
}
```

Basically this should work.

Comment: if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(this.state.datas)) {
      var RowsBaby = this.props.datas.map(function(data) {
        return (
            <Row title={data.title} />
        )
      });
    } else {
      var RowsBaby = <Row title="not loading" />
    }    

That is the code I added and it gives me  

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined 

Againt it is not able to read the object.

Comment: you don't need to use jquery and also I think your check isn't written properly I edited my post

Comment: Thank you. I have reversed the logic in the if statement. Sorry. It is working now. thank you.